# Why is ActiveJob InlineAdapter not used in request tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activejob

I have this code in my test.rb :

```rb
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline
```

In the test I have:

```rb
scenario '15 minutes after last call a recall should happen' do    
  p ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter
end
```

This returns:
**ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::InlineAdapter**

which is good because the perform_later are executed immediately.

However when I add **type: :request** to the test like this:

```rb
scenario '15 minutes after last call a recall should happen', type: :request do    
  p ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter
end
```

i'm getting: **requestActiveJob::QueueAdapters::TestAdapter** and the perform_later isn't executed anymore.  Is this intended behaviour?  How can I make sure the perform_later blocks are always executed in tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37270

Putting

```
(ActiveJob::Base.descendants << ActiveJob::Base).each(&:disable_test_adapter)
```

IN the actual test fixes it.

Another more cleaner option is to (if possible) change the test type into: **type: :system** and making sure your rspec-rails version is >= 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Jobs are not enqueued to be performed, but they are enqueued to be checked if they were enqueued ([basically just saved in an array](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/test_adapter.rb#L52) so you can test if they are there):

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters/TestAdapter.html

Since you tagged this question with rspec, then there's perfect matcher for you: [`have_been_enqueued`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-9/docs/matchers/have-been-enqueued-matcher) which can be used like this:

```
RSpec.describe UploadBackupsJob do
  it "matches with enqueued job" do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
    UploadBackupsJob.perform_later
    expect(UploadBackupsJob).to have_been_enqueued
  end
end
```

Comment: How can I make sure the perform_later blocks are always executed in tests?  When type request is not included, they are executed. Why is it using a different queue adapter even though I specified I want the inline adapter?